ESP32 rebooting on gpio LOW
I am using esp32-wroom-32 module to turn on/off the 24v electronic solenoid valve using 5v relay. Detailed circuit is shown in the image below. However according to my observation whenever the solenoid valve is connected to the circuit, and if the GPIO is made HIGH the solenoid valve turns on, but after that if the GPIO is made LOW, then at that point esp32 restarts/reboots. This observation is seen whenever the solenoid valve is connected to the circuit, if I remove it and run the sketch it works fine. My question here is what is the solution for this as i have no idea about detailed electronics. 
